# How to get data from setResult when the app is closed in Android

Tags: android

I am sorry in advance i could to find a better title for question. I will explain it here.

I am starting a activity with `startActivityForResult()` now user perform some task and result data is generated and instead of pressing back button user decided to close application. Now how do i get the result data because when user closes application `onActivityResult()` is not called and i cannot save result data to database.

It would be great if you could provide me with sample code or just expalanation.

Comment: Just save the info in sharedprefs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is take the input from the user and **save it** in the [SharedPreference](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) or database (SQLite) for recovery purposes. And when the user opens the app next time retrieve the data from the database.

You can use the [Android Room library](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room) for database.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the onDestroy() lifecycle method. And there implement the logic as explained by https://stackoverflow.com/a/66765711/11942163.